# Can't login to dashboard or create a member account

Tags: joomla, user-dashboard

I get the following error when trying to create a member account login or creating a directory.

0 -   @import url(/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/css/civicrm.css); @import url(/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css);    Sorry, due to an error, we are unable to fulfill your request at the moment. You may want to contact your administrator or service provider with more details about what action you were performing when this occurred. You must be logged in to view this page.

[Return to home page.](http://www.olivebranch-iac.org/)

function toggle( element ) { var parent = element.parentNode; var className = parent.className; if ( className == 'crm-accordion-wrapper collapsed crm-fatal-error-details-block') { parent.className = 'crm-accordion-wrapper crm-fatal-error-details-block'; } else { parent.className = 'crm-accordion-wrapper collapsed crm-fatal-error-details-block'; } }

Comment: Can you check civicrm log to find more detail about the error?

Comment: Can you give me the location of the log file?